# How can I properly mimic this encryption method to produce the proper value for the encryptedPwd field?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, cryptography, reverse-engineering

## *Background*

I'm needing to pull reports from Amazon's Seller Central portal for multiple clients of ours on a weekly basis via a python script. I try to avoid webdrivers due to their inconsistent, error-prone nature across different OSes (from experience). Therefore, I figured it would be a fun little project (and maybe, ultimately, exercise in futility) to try reverse-engineering the login process for sellercentral.amazon.com. The process isn't difficult, save for two fields in the initial login form: `password` and `metadata1`. The `password` field is discussed in detail below. The `metadata1` field seems to employ a similar technique, while introducing the additional hurdle of changing every few seconds. When i monitored the `metadata1` value it appeared to be generated using a large json object of the various browser metrics. But, one thing at a time, so I'll focus on the password encryption in this post and worry about `metadata1` in a future post.

## *Getting to the point*

Upon form submission the value in the `password` field is encrypted using techniques discussed further down in this post. The resulting encrypted value then replaces the value in the the password field and renames the field `encryptedPwd`

## *My Findings*

So far, I've been reviewing the javascript files and stepping through the code sequences and have learned the following:

- They're utilizing a proprietary [SiegeCrypto.js](https://github.com/Anirudh-R-2506/phisherman/blob/fdc44f2ebcba046e063a2ec0be531c091a5db1ae/sites/amazon/signin/Amazon%20Sign-In-pwd_files/81JZFvi7%2BTL.js) script as the main cryptographic library (Siege being Amazon's Secure Ingress and Egress Team) & [SubtleCrypto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto) as a part of the process for generating the encryptedPwd
    - SiegeCrypto is first found in [AuthenticationPortalSigninNA.js](https://github.com/Anirudh-R-2506/phisherman/blob/fdc44f2ebcba046e063a2ec0be531c091a5db1ae/sites/amazon/signin/Amazon%20Sign-In-pwd_files/AuthenticationPortalSigninNA.js), declaring the basic initial encryption definition:

```js
SiegeCrypto.addProfile("AuthenticationPortalSigninNA", {
  "password": {dataType: "AuthPortalSigninPasswordNA", requiresTail: false},
});
...
SiegeCrypto.addDataType({
    "dataTypeId": "AuthPortalSigninPasswordNA",
    "jwkPublicKey": {"kty":"RSA","e":"AQAB","n":"gXXZV1VqZ6k_uQtyJNJy5q-qvKdqrXJNgKUO1aYc1UPBVqlhCP0GPxf-0GSo-LEtArgcbF8-j6_vSLSqztYxxF8og--rB8zAyZ8DXZaugX-UiJDQnoJL_HtXKuwIm9U7oEPoeD6H4ZDcfbsPj77xVn7UA2-a90N4aZqMC8EIfXIy1tqSbSPnxPOaiEmy8xGtG-L3RdCyc7TL0Swd_f0_DjRT6ip91IBlCmquoa-xJgZ9e44PVH4AwdyssiV4ZLEZ5yFcE0zcRb_62kx_TQptidbJ4nHocFVjmUW9YsrAWeKrBmOGZEjO4vbATYs1Yf4vgcH7Ix61EPR5sbDP4SlBWQ"},
    "providerId": "si:md5",
    "keyId": "56d14edce8e2cb6c6842c59ddaee426e"
});
```

Stepping through the code I was able to find more specifics of the algorithm

```
*profile* (used by SiegeCrypto)
- password: {dataType: "AuthPortalSigninPasswordNA", requiresTail: false}
*publicKeyProvider* (added as a DataType to SiegeCrypto)
- keyId: 56d14edce8e2cb6c6842c59ddaee426e
- providerId: si:md5
*wrapKey*
- wrappingAlgorithm
  - name: RSA-OAEP
  - hash: SHA-256
  - modulusLength: 2048
  - publicExponent: [1, 0, 1]
*Additional Fields*
name: aes_128_gcm_iv12_tag16
encryption: AES-GCM
ivLength: 12
keyLength: 128
tagLength: 128
```

Later in the process I was able to find the following, which I'm assuming is the parameters amidst being processed according to the encryptions specifications above, but i have no idea how to get to that point

```
cipherMessage: Uint8Array(413) [1, 128, 0, 20, 124, 132, 165, 153, 149, 96, 94, 4, 210, ...]
messageHeader:
- algorithmId: 20
- contentType: 2
- encryptedDataKeys: [{"keyInfo": "56d14edce8e2cb6c6842c59ddaee426e"}]
- encryptionContext: {}
- frameLength: 12
- headerIvLength: 12
- messageId: Uint8Array(16) [124, 132, 165, 153, 149, 96, ...]
- type: 128
- version: 1
```

Looking over Amazon's AWS Encryption SDK ([Python Repo](https://github.com/aws/aws-encryption-sdk-python/blob/master/src/aws_encryption_sdk/identifiers.py)) I've found the following three pieces that seem to be what I need. However, I'm not sure where to go from here.

```py
# algorithm, mode, data_key_length, iv_length, auth_length, auth_key_length=0
EncryptionSuite.AES_128_GCM_IV12_TAG16 = (algorithms.AES, modes.GCM, 16, 12, 16)

# algorithm_id,  encryption, message_format_version
AlgorithmSuite.AES_128_GCM_IV12_TAG16 = (0x0014, EncryptionSuite.AES_128_GCM_IV12_TAG16, 0x01)

# encryption_type, algorithm, padding_type, padding_algorithm, padding_mgf
WrappingAlgorithm.RSA_OAEP_SHA256_MGF1 = (EncryptionType.ASYMMETRIC, rsa, padding.OAEP, hashes.SHA256, padding.MGF1)
```

## The Question

Can someone provide a short python snippet utilizing the above encryption techniques along with an explanation, so I can see how the `encryptedPwd` field value is generated? Here's a dummy password to demonstrate with: Blamazon123

Two example values of the above dummy password as `encryptedPwd` (I've added spaces where I saw consistences):

```
AYAAF  P/a2u8yLSNjLWzPRIi0Bac  AAAABAAZzaTptZDUAIDU2ZDE0ZWRjZThlMmNiNmM2ODQyYzU5ZGRhZWU0MjZlAQ  Brthm+db6k/Oo832X/5U+JtXcBrVnCetjOnvcypG5ZZ6xZr0rXDDMctQevThwGjGYqOOQTy6tFALgMHnjWC2bcBBtyKMhUflpCjGTRodjE7btdqrgExEr07k1ErejaQ1vAW8hQSedfsQR3gyWxJcKKlQ91B4CYO5UMMJzevQyln0SASh5MLW6xOHMnjwdHI8aKFw2ErcvIFg5OpqCDSIyPjifvxkSTue7gJ3fB0ACda04EA5wxmkRteCF753kVGYNBD0h9eOHCPcCm/Y7bWoJAelvqu/U/LxAPkl216deDko4oxjVqLeRy/IExbx6cdEDT7zu0U7HROhvstu8TZE1f  AgAAAAAMAAAADAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA  O0Gt/txLoiiXlGQcb5dyFn/////  AAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAv  LEJ4zlnbivrzliBrcFGIsPBU3srfmTu91dw4=
AYAAF  L1E3ydr57mIKpAQtOrAPsE  AAAABAAZzaTptZDUAIDU2ZDE0ZWRjZThlMmNiNmM2ODQyYzU5ZGRhZWU0MjZlAQ  AUJX+8tRKZESh1o09BLe6Qj13iuyP5Kb2IC/ipA1mRlWIQtIYApU8792+f5U2x8wv7rTVHcKM8wnFXP2I78PCbo4kXwV5Q6JE99bV4BP+5YnzB1YI6XUgrZ2ubm1wcSV3W1K3OhMogcXIbWjeEjKj2WmpVgSgCXKS6+Z6GxMnE+hArZlNIATYojL7IlLPR5kiGzN4pq86gLzGbfcG2at1MNQ5DdrJtktixLJPU1oFwCtT4AFfy6kiGfoepN+VE0AK0ysMyX3FY7QaI9qLtuA20zQX52NbLzG/qSENYohHzgvOOVzCIr4uwyJ3uXSA0kKXEJ4IbWmQ+k30cotoWRSJW  AgAAAAAMAAAADAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA  NUNRLibdfG4P1ac0dL8Ka//////  AAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAv  4vyjW2MLIuuBm8D1c41v5ZwEQFk8k/p4GOss=
```

## Adding Additional Source Code with Analysis

The javascript file largely responsible for generating the `metadata1` field can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/caffeinatedMike/b49bfe4cb179f90626dca3c726dcfd95). I've decrypted the functions that I saw were part of the `metadata1` generation process. They start on the following lines:

- 1827 (relates to `encryptedPwd`) adds the encryption eventlistener to the form submit action
- 332 the core generating function that dispatches the encrypting steps
- 789 & 810 create a crcTable that's used in generating
- 1839 calculates a checksum (used in the `metadata1` process)
- 2540 is where the `metadata1` values are returned (from line 332)
- 2672 and 2704 are where I noticed the email being converted a hex value, that is prefixed to the `metadata1` contents before it's encrypted

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/kinabalu/kindleclipper/blob/master/app.py) some kind of logging to get info for kindle, so it might help.

Comment: Those look a lot like JWT tokens, see https://jwt.io/. The string `jwkPublicKey` strongly hints at JWT as well.

Comment: I suspect the metadata1 object is going to be crucial; it is almost certainly used to prevent automated logins. It is probably used in the same way captchas work: increasing confidence that there is a human being interacting with the browser.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm looking to do something similar. Decrypting the metadata1 doesn't seem to have yielded anything about how the `encryptedPwd` field is generated.

Comment: @webnoob See mkb79's answer. It provides insight into how to properly generate it.

Comment: @CaffeinatedMike Thanks, I get that part but I'm struggling with actually authenticating at the moment. Even using the generated version on the web page, I can't seem to sign in using nodejs. I can manage in postman though

Comment: @CaffeinatedMike Can you explain a little more how decrypting the metadata1 field helps in generating the encryptedPwd field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `metadata1`  is encrypted in XXTEA. I‘ve wrote a Python script to decode and encode the `metadata1`. This can be found [here](https://github.com/mkb79/Audible/blob/master/src/audible/metadata.py).